# Why can I not see JSON data returned from PHP with jquery post?

Tags: php, jquery

I'm making a jquery post call like so:

```
   var t1 = $("#form").serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "save_test.php",
        data: t1,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){

            if (data.st) {
                alert("Success");
            }
            else if (data.error) {
                alert("Error");
            }                
        }
    });
```

My PHP Looks like this for my error test:

```
$res = new stdClass();

$res->error = 'ERROR SEEN';
echo json_encode($res);
exit();
```

Why can I not access my json encoded data returned from PHP? I would expect this to trigger my data.error alert.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `datatype:json` in jquery code

or you can use

```
var d=$.parseJSON(data)
```

then  use `d.st`

Comment: That was it, I wasn't parsing the JSON returned from PHP.  Thanks!